# Python Remove Punctuation but no Emoticons

Tags: python

Basically, I have a tweet and want to remove the punctuation, but I don't want to remove the Emoticon
How can?
i have the list of emoticons

```
emoticons = [':)','(:',':-)','(-:','=)']

exclude = set(string.punctuation)
remove = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
```

But I don't know how to keep the emoticons 
i need a condition that keeps the emoticon based on the list i already have and then just delete the punctuation.

Comment: I suspect the neatest way to do this would be with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) from Python's [tag:regex] library using [tag:negative-lookahead]s.

Comment: @user3572183 what do yo mean by punctuation? can you display the output form you want to obtain?

Comment: Thanks guys i already solve it.

Comment: Can you share how you solved it?